# Gradient colored polar curve

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to do the following in gnuplot: color with gradient an ellipse. Each point of the
ellipse has its z-value given by the function

```
charge_density(t,beta) = -sin(t)*beta*(sqrt(1-(beta**2)))/(1-((sin(t)*beta)**2))
```

The radius function of the ellipse is given by a similar function:

```
radius(t,beta) = sqrt(1-(beta**2))/sqrt(1-((sin(t)*beta)**2))
```

Where `beta` is just a parameter satisfying `0<beta<1`, and `t` is the angle.

Well, I tried to use the `"+"` special file with the `lc rgb variable` option, but it doesn't work with polar coordinates.

I also tried the `set mapping cylindrical`, but nothing happened.

Is this possible only with cartesian coordinates? In this case, I'll have to do 2 graphics and modify the above functions...

Or will I have to create a data file with `angle, radius, z` data?

I'd like to do this with `pm3d` and the following `palette`:

```
set palette model RGB defined (-1 "blue", 0 "black", 1 "red")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the code:

```
beta =0.5
charge_density(t,beta) = -sin(t)*beta*(sqrt(1-(sin(t)*beta)**2))/(1-((sin(t)*beta)**2))
radius(t,beta) = sin(t*beta) # your function equals 1!

# convert polar to carthesian
r_x(t)=radius(t,beta)*cos(t)
r_y(t)=radius(t,beta)*sin(t)


set palette model RGB defined (-1 "blue", 0 "black", 1 "red")

set size ratio -1 # same unit length in x and y

# number of sample points.
# increase if curve has edges
set samples 100 

#decouple range of "+" and xrange
set parametric

plot  [0:3*pi] "+" u (r_x($1)):(r_y($1)):(charge_density($1,beta))\
    with lines linewidth 3 linecolor palette
```

and there the result:

[image]

**NOTE:** Your `radius` equals to 1, so I took another function. Also, your `charge_density` has one extra closing parenthesis.

Some comments:

- if you plot with `lc rgb variable`, a 24bit RGB color value is expected:

  `(red*256^2 + green*256 + blue)` with `red, green, blue = 0...255`

  If you want gnuplot to use the color according to the palette, write `lc palette`
- gnuplot 4.6 does not support `"+"` for polar. Also, the `mapping` sets the behavior for 3D plots. However, as your formula calculates a radius for an angle, you can easily transform this to carthesian coordinates and plot these. There is still one drawback: The range given in the `plot` sets the xrange, too. This also means that the "length" of your curve changes when you change the xrange. You can solve this by `set parametric` which causes gnuplot to use a dedicated variable u instead of x when plotting functions. It is nice (and helps you) that this affects the special file `"+"`, too. I do not know if this is a (positive) bug or a feature.

Comment: Sweber, I corrected the functions. Thanks for advising!

Comment: That was exactly what I was needing! Just one thing: although I used `set parametric`, it was the `set xrange` and `set yrange` that worked to change the ranges, not the `set urange` and `set vrange`.

Comment: The point is, the script could contain a `set xrange[-1:1]`. Then, `"+"` goes from -1 to 1, too. So, your parameter depends on the xrange, what is not what you want here. If you use `plot [0:3*pi] "+"...`, the xrange will automatically be set to [0:9.4], overriding your `set xrange` command. But with `parametric`, it doesn't. And yes, the `set urange` has no effect here. As said, it's a bit strange.