# Gnuplot : convert or rewrite parametric or polar functions for the palette linecolor

Tags: plot, graph, gnuplot, transformation, parametric-equations

What are the rules to formulate either polar or parametric equations in gnuplot such that the `palette` linecolor can be used?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74828702/gnuplot-parametric-equation-positive-variable-ok-negative-variable-confusing) post explains the plotting of some parametric equations I am interested in, and I would like to rewrite that plot using the `palette` ability of gnuplot as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75759535/gnuplot-plot-function-using-palette-gradient-linecolor-seems-uniform-not-gr). I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076005/gradient-colored-polar-curve) post which shows how this might be possible, so my long-winded attempt to get *anything* close is below - before a brief note: I retained the `beta` parameter only to get the new plot to work before I understand it - i.e. there is no "beta" parameter I am interested in per se, and I see there is a "convert polar to cartesian" in the code, though I do not grasp how it is being used:

```
### parametric plot
reset session

x00(t) = (R + r)*cos(t) - d*cos((R + r)/r*t)
y00(t) = (R + r)*sin(t) - d*sin((R + r)/r*t)
#
beta=1.0
x01(t,beta) = (R + r)*cos(t*beta) - d*cos((R + r)/r*t*beta)
y01(t,beta) = (R + r)*sin(t*beta) - d*sin((R + r)/r*t*beta)
#
zValueForGradient(t,beta)= cos(t*beta)
#
# convert polar to cartesian
r_x(t)=x01(t,beta)*cos(t)
r_y(t)=y01(t,beta)*sin(t)
# #
set palette model RGB defined (-1 "blue", 0 "black", 1 "red")
#
set parametric
set size ratio -1
set grid x,y

set multiplot layout 2,2

    # epicycloid:
    set title "want epicycloid \n with gradient"
    R=3.0; r=1.0  ; d=0.5
    plot [0:2*pi] '+' u (r_x($1)):(r_y($1)):(zValueForGradient($1,beta)) t '' w l lw 2 lc palette

    # hypotrochoid:
    set title "want hypotrochoid \n with gradient"
    R=5.0;  r=-3.0;  d=5.0
    plot [0:3*pi] '+' u (r_x($1)):(r_y($1)):(zValueForGradient($1,beta)) t '' w l lw 2 lc palette


    # epicycloid:
    set title "true epicycloid"
    R=3.0; r=1.0  ; d=0.5
    set xrange[-6:6]
    set yrange[-6:6]
    set trange[0:2*pi]
    plot x00(t),y00(t) w l t '' lw 2 lc "red"

    # hypotrochoid:
    set title "true hypotrochoid"
    R=5.0;  r=-3.0;  d=5.0
    set xrange[-8:8]
    set yrange[-8:8]
    set trange[0:6*pi]
    plot x00(t),y00(t) w l t '' lw 2 lc "blue"


unset multiplot
### end of script
```

the plot looks like this (`wxt 0 enhanced` terminal):
[image]

The attempted plots - with no resemblance of epicycloids or hypotrochoids - are on the top row, the plots of the original functions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74828702/gnuplot-parametric-equation-positive-variable-ok-negative-variable-confusing) plot are on the bottom row. One can clearly see the functions (`x01`, `y01`, `r_x`, `r_y` in the script) are is getting colored according to the `z palette` (`zValueForGradient(t,beta)`). Seems close, but clearly as well, I do not understand how to apply this to functions as described in [the source post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076005/gradient-colored-polar-curve). It is unclear to me how to treat these functions, or to use the approach in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076005/gradient-colored-polar-curve) to get the intended effect.

To reiterate : how should a parametric function be treated in gnuplot so that it will be colored according to `palette`, but also preserve the nature of function itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether I fully understood your question.
Why do you want to convert `x01(t,beta)` and `y01(t,beta)` into cartesian coordinates? They are already in cartesian coordinates. Simply use them directly, e.g. like:

```
plot [0:2*pi] '+' u (x01($1,beta)):(y01($1,beta)):(zValueForGradient($1,beta))

plot [0:6*pi] '+' u (x01($1,beta)):(y01($1,beta)):(zValueForGradient($1,beta))
```

Alternatively, do you maybe want to have a polar plot graph?

**Script:**

```
### parametric plot
reset session

x00(t) = (R + r)*cos(t) - d*cos((R + r)/r*t)
y00(t) = (R + r)*sin(t) - d*sin((R + r)/r*t)
#
beta=1.0
x01(t,beta) = (R + r)*cos(t*beta) - d*cos((R + r)/r*t*beta)
y01(t,beta) = (R + r)*sin(t*beta) - d*sin((R + r)/r*t*beta)
#
zValueForGradient(t,beta)= cos(t*beta)
#
# convert polar to cartesian
r_x(t)=x01(t,beta)*cos(t)
r_y(t)=y01(t,beta)*sin(t)
#
set palette model RGB defined (-1 "blue", 0 "black", 1 "red")
#
set parametric
set size ratio -1
set grid x,y

set multiplot layout 2,2

    # epicycloid:
    set title "want epicycloid \n with gradient"
    R=3.0; r=1.0  ; d=0.5
    plot [0:2*pi] '+' u (x01($1,beta)):(y01($1,beta)):(zValueForGradient($1,beta)) t '' w l lw 2 lc palette

    # hypotrochoid:
    set title "want hypotrochoid \n with gradient"
    R=5.0;  r=-3.0;  d=5.0
    plot [0:6*pi] '+' u (x01($1,beta)):(y01($1,beta)):(zValueForGradient($1,beta)) t '' w l lw 2 lc palette


    # epicycloid:
    set title "true epicycloid"
    R=3.0; r=1.0  ; d=0.5
    set xrange[-6:6]
    set yrange[-6:6]
    set trange[0:2*pi]
    plot x00(t),y00(t) w l t '' lw 2 lc "red"

    # hypotrochoid:
    set title "true hypotrochoid"
    R=5.0;  r=-3.0;  d=5.0
    set xrange[-8:8]
    set yrange[-8:8]
    set trange[0:6*pi]
    plot x00(t),y00(t) w l t '' lw 2 lc "blue"


unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]